# apache webserver virtualhost set password for localhost:port

Tags: apache, webserver, password-protection

I was wondering how would I set password for `localhost:port`.

Here is snip from my httpd.conf file:

```
EnableSendfile on
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

By the way, I am using Nifi on that host and connecting it from other computer by entering this host's IP address and the port number in the browser.

I've seen how setting password is done for directories (that's files located in particular directory) but not for an application running on the host.

Looking forward to hearing from you soon. Thanks.